# Shuffling NumPy array along a given axis

Tags: python, random, numpy

Given the following NumPy array,

```
> a = array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

it's simple enough to shuffle a single row,

```
> shuffle(a[0])
> a
array([[4, 2, 1, 3, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Is it possible to use indexing notation to shuffle each of the rows independently? Or do you have to iterate over the array. I had in mind something like,

```
> numpy.shuffle(a[:])
> a
array([[4, 2, 3, 5, 1],[3, 1, 4, 5, 2],[4, 2, 1, 3, 5]]) # Not the real output
```

though this clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to call `numpy.random.shuffle()` several times because you are shuffling several sequences independently.  `numpy.random.shuffle()` works on any mutable sequence and is not actually a `ufunc`.  The shortest and most efficient code to shuffle all rows of a two-dimensional array `a` separately probably is

```
list(map(numpy.random.shuffle, a))
```

Some people prefer to write this as a list comprehension instead:

```
[numpy.random.shuffle(x) for x in a]
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and clean solution.

Comment: at least for python 3.5, numpy 1.10.2, this doesn't work, a remains unchanged.

Comment: @drevicko: What dimension does your array have?  This answer is for shuffling all rows of a two-dimensional array (and I'm sure it also works with your combination of Python and Numpy versions).

Comment: Aha! I see what happened: in Python 3.5, map is lazy, producing an iterator, and doesn't do the mapping until you iterate through it. If you do e.g.: `for _ in map(...): pass` it'll work.

Comment: @drevicko That makes sense.  It might be best to write that code as `for x in a: numpy.random.shuffle(x)` then.

Comment: I guess so.. You do get a view when you iterate over `a`, don't you? There's also a messy one-liner: `list(map(...))` if `a` isn't too big, but a for loop starts to look more attractive ;)

Comment: @drevicko The for loop basically does the same as `map()`: it uses Python's iterator protocol to iterate over `a`.  It calls `a.__iter__()` to retrieve an iterator for `a`, and then calls the `__next__()` method on that iterator until `StopIteration` is raised.  In this particular case, with `a` being a two-dimensional Numpy array, the items returned by the `__next__()` method are indeed views for the respective rows.  In case of a one-dimensional array, you'd simply get the values of the elements.

Comment: or `[*map(numpy.random.shuffle, a)]` to be simpler.

Answer (score 32):

#### Vectorized solution with `rand+argsort` trick

We could generate unique indices along the specified axis and index into the the input array with `advanced-indexing`. To generate the unique indices, we would use [`random float generation + sort` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438143/), thus giving us a vectorized solution. We would also generalize it to cover generic `n-dim` arrays and along generic `axes` with [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html). The final implementation would look something like this -

```
def shuffle_along_axis(a, axis):
    idx = np.random.rand(*a.shape).argsort(axis=axis)
    return np.take_along_axis(a,idx,axis=axis)
```

Note that this shuffle won't be in-place and returns a shuffled copy.

Sample run -

```
In [33]: a
Out[33]: 
array([[18, 95, 45, 33],
       [40, 78, 31, 52],
       [75, 49, 42, 94]])

In [34]: shuffle_along_axis(a, axis=0)
Out[34]: 
array([[75, 78, 42, 94],
       [40, 49, 45, 52],
       [18, 95, 31, 33]])

In [35]: shuffle_along_axis(a, axis=1)
Out[35]: 
array([[45, 18, 33, 95],
       [31, 78, 52, 40],
       [42, 75, 94, 49]])
```

Comment: Interesting solution! However I made a quick experiment and it was way slower (on the order of 1000x) then the naiive solution below which repeatedly invokes rng.shuffle. Can anyone confirm this? Why is it so slow?

Comment: @Nils I am not sure the naive solution you are referring is still here but an explanation would be that rng.shuffle shuffles only does in-place shuffling (O(n) time complexity). For this solution you have to allocate memory for the unique indices, do sorting with argsort (O(nlogn) time complexity), and then you have to allocate new memory for the result as well. Thus the naive solution scales better for large arrays.

Answer (score 11):

For those looking at this question more recently, `numpy` provides the [`permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html) method to shuffle an array *independently* along the specified axis.

From their documentation (using `random.Generator`)

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = np.arange(24).reshape(3, 8)
x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])

y = rng.permuted(x, axis=1)
y
array([[ 4,  3,  6,  7,  1,  2,  5,  0],  
       [15, 10, 14,  9, 12, 11,  8, 13],
       [17, 16, 20, 21, 18, 22, 23, 19]])
```

Comment: Great answer and exactly what I was looking for - this is the canonical way to do this now.