# Randomly permute each value across the channel dimension independently for each pixel of a PIL image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I would like to have a function that randomly permute the value of each pixel according to the dimensions of the channels in the image using PIL.

I tried some methods but I didn't get the right result or it's too slow.

EDIT

**Example**: For the pixel 1 suppose that the values are R: 42 G: 13 B:37, we apply the function and for this pixel the new values will be R: 13 G: 42 B:37 (for this pixel the permutation was 0,1,2 -> 1,0,2) For 2 it will be another random permutation for example 0,1,2 -> 2, 1, 0 etc ...

[image: Example]

Comment: *"randomly permute... according to dimensions of channels"*?  What does that mean - do you have an example please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell For the pixel (0,0) suppose that the values are R: 42 G: 13 B:37, we apply the function and for this pixel the new values will be R: 13 G: 42 B:37 (for this pixel the permutation was 0,1,2 -> 1,0,2)

For another pixel (0,1) it will be another random permutation for example 0,1,2 -> 2, 1, 0 etc ....

Do you understand my question now?

Comment: @Divakar has the solution here, you need to shuffle along axis=2... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317373/2836621

Comment: Sorry, if you didn't know you can convert your PIL Image to Numpy array like this `na = np.array(PILImage)` and use Divakar's technique then convert your Numpy array back to PIL Image with `PILImage = Image.fromarray(na)`

Comment: I'm intrigued as to the purpose of this?

Comment: We're going to try this as a data augmentation

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Little late but..

My first thought would be to do this in NumPy or another library

```py
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

im = Image("./file")
permutations = list(permutations(range(3), 3))  # All possible permutations
rearranged = np.array(im)[..., list(permutations[randint(0, 5)])]
result = Image.fromarray(rearranged)
```

Something similar can be done without conversion to NumPy

```py
from itertools import permutations
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

rgb_split = im.split()  # list corresponding to R, G, and B
permutations = list(permutations(range(3), 3))  # All possible permutations
selected = list(permutations[randint(0, 5)])
result = Image.merge("RGB", (rgb_split[selected[0]],
                         rgb_split[selected[1]],
                         rgb_split[selected[2]])
```